# Unpermitted parameter nested form inside a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Workgroup object, which has many resource_quantities. The Resource_quantity belongs to a resource. I want a form that can create the Workgroup and its children resource_quantities all in one place. I am trying to build a form using nested attributes. My problem is that when I submit my form where I can add many resources_quantities and their related resource, I get

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "workgroup"=>{"name"=>"Living room", "description"=>"installation floor", "contractor_id"=>"1", "resource_quantities_attributes"=>{"1543577850668"=>{"quantity"=>"22", "resources"=>{"name"=>"wood", "unit_type"=>"Matériel", "purchase_price"=>"20", "price"=>"22", "unit_measure"=>"u", "vat"=>"12"}, "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Workgroup"}
```

The fact that I receive a resources params instead of a resource_attributes results in a Unpermitted parameter: :resources. I have tried this params.require(:workgroup).permit! but i still received resources which results in a unknown attribute 'resources' for ResourceQuantity.

Here are the useful piece of code:

**Workgroups controller**

```
def new
    @workgroup = Workgroup.new
    @workgroup.resource_quantities.build.build_resource
 end

 def create
    @workgroup =  Workgroup.new(workgroup_params)

    if @workgroup.save!
      raise
      redirect_to resources_path, notice: 'Resource was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end


 def workgroup_params
    params.require(:workgroup).permit(:name, :description, :contractor_id, :_destroy, {resource_quantities_attributes: [:quantity, :_destroy, {resources_attributes: [ :name, :unit_type, :price, :contractor_id, :purchase_price, :unit_measure, :vat]}]})
 end
```

**My Three Models**

```
class Workgroup < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :resource_quantities, inverse_of: :workgroup
  has_many :resources, through: :resource_quantities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :resource_quantities, allow_destroy: true
 end

 class ResourceQuantity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :workgroup, optional: true
  belongs_to :resource, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :resource, :allow_destroy => true
 end

 class Resource < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :workgroups, through: :resource_quantities
  has_many :resource_quantities, inverse_of: :resource
end
```

**My form for Workgroup which integrate the form for resource_quantities**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@workgroup) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.association :contractor, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: f.object.contractor || "#{current_user.contractor.id}"} %>


    <h3> Resources </h3>

    <table class='large_table'>
      <tbody class="add_resource">

        <%= f.simple_fields_for :resource_quantities do |builder| %>
          <%= render 'resource_quantity_fields', f: builder %>
        <% end %>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Ajouter une resource', f, :resource_quantities, class: 'btn btn-primary', data: { association_insertion_node: '.add_resource', association_insertion_method: :append } %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**This is my partial to add the fields related to resource_quantity and resource**

```
<tr class="nested-fields">

    <td>
      <%= f.input :quantity %>
    </td>

      <%= f.simple_fields_for :resources do |e| %>

      <td><%= e.input :name %></td>
      <td><%= e.input :unit_type, collection: Resource::TYPES %></td>
      <td><%= e.input :purchase_price %></td>
      <td><%= e.input :price %></td>
      <td><%= e.input :unit_measure, collection: Resource::UNIT_MEASURE%></td>
      <td><%= e.input :vat, collection: Resource::VAT%></td>



    <td>
      <%= link_to_remove_association theme_icon_tag("trash"), f %>
    </td>

     <% end %>
</tr>
```

Hope someone will be able to help me I am rookie in rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that by putting resources_attributes into a string is enabling me to get the right params in the consol.

```
  simple_fields_for "resources_attributes" do |e|
```

I don't know if it is good practice but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following change?

Replace

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :resources do |e| %>
```

with

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :resources_attributes do |e| %>
```

Comment: Ok I have tried your solution but it doesn't help :D Nevertheless when I put simple_fields_for "resources_attributes" do |e| it does the job. Thank you for sharing your thought it helped me to find the solution anyway.